# restrict customer from adding product to cart

Tags: magento2

HI am trying to restrict customer from adding product to cart.
i have a condition where i want to check the item type in the cart if customer adds the same product type to the cart then it should be success else if the product in cart does not match with the product type then its should show an error and should be added to cart

below is my code to restrict product from adding cart but its not working

**RestrictAddToCart.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;


    protected $_cart;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_request;
   protected $collectionFactory;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $product;
 protected $checkoutSession;
  protected $product;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
         \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
          \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_request = $request; 
         $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory; 
         $this->product = $product;
         $this->formKey = $formKey;
          $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;      
    }


    public function getProductCollection()
            {
                $productCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
                $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                foreach ($productCollection as $product){
                     echo 'id  =  '.$product->getTypeId().'<br>';

                } 

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $productId = $product->getTypeId();
          $params = array(
            'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
            'product_id' => $productId, //product Id
            'qty'   => 1 //quantity of product
          );


        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
       $_product = $this->product->create()->load($productId);
        $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);

        $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($_product);
        if ($item == $productId) {
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
        } else {
            echo "please remove ". $productId;
        }


    }
}
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add">
        <observer name="customname" instance="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer\RestrictAddToCart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

any help on this thankss

Answer (score 0):

Use checkout_cart_product_add_before event as below

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_before">
        <observer name="restrict_product_addtocart" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\RestrictProductAddToCart" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/RestrictProductAddToCart.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class RestrictProductAddToCart implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

        if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') { //your condition
            //your code
            throw new LocalizedException(__('You are not allowed to add this product to cart.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response please check the updated questions i have also reviewed your code however i know it will work for configurable type product but the challenge is check product type dynamically this will stop all the configurable type product to be added in cart